# React-redux: Subsequent same-type sibling components don't change with different Prop values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Sharing the codeSandBox of the project with removed bloat: https://codesandbox.io/s/finding-memo-wb753?file=/src/index.js

Problem: After the options, of a Datalist within a leaf-level component(vehicleList), are rendered for first parent component, they persist for the subsequent sibling (of the parent) components(SectionalPanel).

Key things: The Leaf-level components are updating as intended if they don't use props, i.e. PlanetList. I tried using useRef(), useState(), useEffect() in various ways in the past 3 days. The console log even shows the prop is updated. And everything as it should be under the hood, but doesn't render according to new value of prop.

I cannot understand the problem to begin solving it. Console shows it's fine, but the visuals say it's not fine.

Object representation of components:

```
MainSection:
{ 
  SectionalPanel : {PlanetList, VehicleList},
  SectionalPanel : {PlanetList, VehicleList},
  SectionalPanel : {PlanetList, VehicleList},
  SectionalPanel : {PlanetList, VehicleList}
}
```

Context:

1. MainSection component uses selector to show/hide 4 child components of same type ‘SelectionPanel’.
2. Each SelectionPanel has an img element(redundant here) and a PlanetList and VehicleList components. PlanetList is given a method prop that changes Image according to selected Planet. VehicleList is given distance prop, selected according to selected planet(from child planet component). Panels given keys and tested to give children keys as well.
3. PlanetList has input and datalist. Datalist options are updated successfully according to planets still not selected.
4. VehicleList has input and datalist as well. Options updated, successfully first time but unsuccessfully next, according to vehicles left in inventory and if its range can reach the selected planet.

TL;DR - Multiple sibling components of same type. Their children components update if they don’t use props, but the one that uses intermediate prop doesn’t update/re-render with updated prop, even though prop changes in console.

I have tried useRef(), useEffect(), useState() for options, distanceToPlanet to no avail. Can’t figure out what the problem is.

Edit: I'll keep the answer as is because it was vital as well, but wasn't the solution to this bug. I, finally, solved it by assigning passed in prop as ID to the datalist jsx. Datalists with static ID, even in separate components will cause this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reducers are mutating state:

```js
case SELECT_VEHICLE.REPLACE:
      return {
        ...state,
        vehicleArray: state.vehicleArray.map((vehicle) => {
          if (vehicle.name === action.previousVehicleName) {
            // this mutates the existing object - don't do this!
            vehicle["total_no"] += 1;
            vehicle.selected = false;
          } else if (vehicle.name === action.newVehicleName) {
            vehicle["total_no"] -= 1;
            vehicle.selected = true;
          }
          return vehicle;
        })
      };
```

This is the #1 most frequent bug with Redux - [reducers must *never* mutate state!](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state), and mutations will usually cause your UI to think that nothing has changed and skip updating.  You need to rework this code to use immutable updates.

The best way to do this is to switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which is our recommended approach for writing Redux logic.  It uses Immer inside to let you write "mutating" syntax that is turned into safe and correct immutable updates, which both simplifies your code *and* prevents accidental mutations.

See how to switch to using RTK in the Redux docs "Redux Fundamentals" tutorial here:

https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I thought I'd bypassed mutation by the spread operator... Didn't factor in the rest of operations. I'll look into your suggestions right away.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, it seemed like the obvious problem area and I set it up according to the various tutorials given. But, it hasn't solved it. deepFreeze doesn't give an error on the state in that reducer either. I'll keep looking into it and try to refactor the original project. Thanks for helping me learn a new tool though.